# Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'hwndSource' as it is not available at this instruction pointer

Tags: c#, .net, interop, clipboard

I'm playing around with Interops and I thought: "Hey let's code something that accesses the clipboard ..." so I googled and found some articles (yeah I'm doing it with WPF - .Net 3.5).

However the following method generates an error (as seen in the title) and throws a stackoverflow.

```
private void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Hook to Clipboard
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    if (hwndSource != null)
    {
        installedHandle = hwndSource.Handle;
        viewerHandle = SetClipboardViewer(installedHandle);
        hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.hwndSourceHook));
    }
    // End Hook to Clipboard 
}
```

I have (really) no idea what's going on there.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Stackoverflow usually means an endless loop. Check you call stack and choose to view external code. Try to see what action raises an event that calls your method again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the call to `base.OnSourceInitialized`. You should call the base implementation when you're overriding the method, but it's not the case here : you're handling an event, not overriding a method.

Since the `SourceInitialized` event is raised by the `OnSourceInitialized` method, if you call `OnSourceInitialized` from the event, it will raise the event again. So you have an infinite recursion, which eventually causes a stack overflow.

So you have 2 options to fix the problem:

- override `OnSourceInitialized` rather than handling the `SourceInitialized` event
- remove the call to `base.OnSourceInitialized`

Comment: Thanks, I was all wrapped up in Interops, didn't think of this one.